# testng.xml not running class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am right clicking on my testng.xml and running as a testng Suite, but the class inside it doesn't run.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="mytestpack" >

 <test name="Firefox Test">

 <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/> 

 <classes>

 <class name="mytestpack.MyTestClass" />

 </classes>

 </test>


</suite>
```

This is the MyTestClass code:

```
package testing_pack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTestClass {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters({"browser"})
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(String browser) {

         System.out.println(browser);

              // If the browser is Firefox, then do this

              if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

                  driver = new FirefoxDriver();

              // If browser is IE, then do this   

              }
         }


    @Test
    public static void test() {

          driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in");
          String i = driver.getCurrentUrl();
          System.out.println(i);

    }
    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
    }
    }
```

The class runs perfectly fine on it's own. Don't understand why testng isn't running it. It doesn't throw any errors it just displays:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Laptops\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\testproject\src\mytestpack\testng.xml


===============================================
mytestpack
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain how you run it? From command line or IDE?

Comment: @Elsid Make sure that you mention the fully qualified name of the class. If you are using eclipse , highlight the class name , then right click and in the contextmenu , select "Copy qualified name" option. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your suite name in `testng.xml` from `mytestpack` to `testing_pack`. The class `MyTestClass` is under different package.

Comment: having another issue now with maven will post new question please check it out if you have time.